# since X variables are in a list, call a function with X parameters

Tags: python

I have `mylist = [var1, var2, var3... varn]`.

`os.path.join` is called not one list, but with many vars.

I can't call `os.path.join(mylist)`.

How to call `os.path.join(var1, var2, var3... varn)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
os.path.join(*mylist)
```

Comment: This is called [unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).